# split character vector with each distinct element having an equal amount of bins

Tags: r, vector, sequence

```
x <- rep(c("A","B","C"),times=c(6,8,3))
 "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

I'm struggling to create a vector that corresponds to each letter being divided into exactly 3 bins:

```
       (A A A A A A  B B B B B B B B  C C C)
x_bin = 1 1 2 2 3 3  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3  1 2 3
```

In this example, I can divide `A` into 3 bins by combining every 2 values. I can divide `B` into 3 bins by combining 3, 3 and 2 values. And I can only divide `C` into 3 bins by combining 1 value.

Is there a function that allows me to do this? I tried with `cut` and `dplyr` but `cut` only works with numeric data and it doesn't cut the way I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** We can use ave/cut like this:

```
ave(x == x, x, FUN = \(x) cut(seq_along(x), 3))
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 3
```

**2)** Another possiblity is unlist/tapply/cut:

```
unlist(tapply(x, x, \(x) cut(seq_along(x), 3, FALSE)))
## A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 C1 C2 C3 
##  1  1  2  2  3  3  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  3  1  2  3
```

### Update

Minor improvement to (1) and add (2).

Answer (score 6):

We can use `ave` to group by letter, then `rep(1:3, length.out=)` to get it to the right length. This guarantees that the numbered groups (per letter) will be either equally balanced or off by no more than 1.

```r
ave(rep(1L, length(x)), x, FUN = function(z) rep(1:3, length.out = length(z)))
#  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3
```

If you want all 1s first, 2s second, etc, then we can `sort` them:

```r
ave(rep(1L, length(x)), x, FUN = function(z) sort(rep(1:3, length.out = length(z))))
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 3
```

Verification:

```r
ave(rep(1L, length(x)), x, FUN = function(z) sort(rep(1:3, length.out = length(z)))) |>
  all.equal(x_bin)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Data

```r
x <- rep(c("A","B","C"),times=c(6,8,3))
x_bin <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `sort` is a good idea, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

- Try `rep` within `ave`

```
ave(
    seq_along(x),
    x,
    FUN = \(v) {
        rep(1:3,
            each = ceiling(length(v) / 3),
            length.out = length(v)
        )
    }
)
```

- Or, another trick with `matrix` within `ave`

```
ave(
    seq_along(x),
    x,
    FUN = \(v)
    col(matrix(nrow = ceiling(length(v) / 3), ncol = 3))[seq_along(v)]
)
```

which should give

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: `each=` is another good idea :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- rep(c("A","B","C"),times=c(6,8,3))
xdf <- data.frame(x = x)

library(tidyverse)
xdf |> group_by(x) |> mutate(bin = rep(1:3, length.out = n())) |> arrange(x, bin)
```

gives

```
  x       bin
   <chr> <int>
 1 A         1
 2 A         1
 3 A         2
 4 A         2
 5 A         3
 6 A         3
 7 B         1
 8 B         1
 9 B         1
10 B         2
11 B         2
12 B         2
13 B         3
14 B         3
15 C         1
16 C         2
17 C         3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `rle` + `rep`:

```r
with(rle(x),
     sapply(seq(length(values)), 
            \(z) rep(1:3, 
                     each = ceiling(lengths[z] / 3), 
                     length.out = lengths[z]))
     ) |> 
  unlist()

#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
times <- c(6,8,3)
x <- rep(c("A","B","C"),times=times)
CUT <- ceiling(times / 3)
x_bin <- unlist(sapply(CUT, function(x)  rep(seq(3), each = x)))

x_bin
#>  [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
> table(x) |> Map(\(...) sort(rep_len(...)), list(1:3), length.out=_) |> unlist()
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 3
```

Length of bins n=3 is defined in `list(1:3)`.